# Xcode 5.02 crash on opening any xib - Yosemite

Tags: xcode

I am running Yosemite 10.10.4 on a Macbook Air. I have a number of Xcode projects that worked successfully under Xcode 6.4. However, I downloaded Xcode 5.02 from Apple in order to use the Big Nerd Ranch book "IOS Programming" which is written for Xcode 5. Any time I open a xib file, Xcode crashes. As suggested, I opened the console app,found the crash log, and copied it.

```
Process:               Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool [1370]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Overlays/Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool
Identifier:            Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool
Version:               4.3 (141)
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        Xcode [1315]
Responsible:           Xcode [1315]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-08-16 17:49:29.223 -0500
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.4 (14E46)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        EFE6107D-FC8B-4F16-13CF-5078BA3A872D

Sleep/Wake UUID:       AC708070-A2AD-4BD3-97E0-72E185438011

Time Awake Since Boot: 2400 seconds
Time Since Wake:       1400 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x94ecb69a __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x92192f19 pthread_kill + 101
2   libsystem_sim_c.dylib           0x02a78e12 abort + 127
3   libsystem_sim_c.dylib           0x02a43900 __assert_rtn + 284
4   libsystem_override.dylib        0x0297e73c _sim_host_bootstrap_init + 264
5   libsystem_override.dylib        0x0297e7aa _sim_host_bootstrap_port + 26
6   libxpc.dylib                    0x02ba4b06 _libxpc_initializer + 870
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x98a9daae libSystem_initializer + 167
8   dyld                            0x8fe710b3 ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 291
9   dyld                            0x8fe71218 ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 64
10  dyld                            0x8fe6d2f0 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 296
11  dyld                            0x8fe6d288 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 192
12  dyld                            0x8fe6d288 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 192
13  dyld                            0x8fe6d288 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 192
14  dyld                            0x8fe6d288 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 192
15  dyld                            0x8fe6d288 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 192
16  dyld                            0x8fe6d288 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 192
17  dyld                            0x8fe6d288 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 192
18  dyld                            0x8fe6d176 ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 120
19  dyld                            0x8fe6d3e1 ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 79
20  dyld                            0x8fe5f125 dyld::initializeMainExecutable() + 183
21  dyld                            0x8fe62bad dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 2793
22  dyld                            0x8fe5e232 dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) + 428
23  dyld                            0x8fe5e047 _dyld_start + 71

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x00000000  ebx: 0x02980015  ecx: 0xbfffd5ac  edx: 0x00000000
  edi: 0xa08481d4  esi: 0x00000006  ebp: 0xbfffd5c8  esp: 0xbfffd5ac
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00000206  eip: 0x94ecb69a   cs: 0x0000000b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0x02a78d93

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00080148
Trap Number:     132
```

Comment: Instead of using out dated tools and out dated tutorials, find a tutorial that uses modern tools.

Comment: Thanks! I moved to the latest Xcode.